# In a ManyToMany birdirectional mapping findAll() gets rows, each containing its children which in-turn contains itself

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I have data model with ManyToMany bidirectional mapping as follows.

A product can have multiple categories, similarly categories can have multiple products. I am using a link table to maintain the relation.

'Categories' entity is defined as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "categories")
class Categories(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="cat_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        var id: Integer,
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "categories_product", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "cat_id")], inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "prd_id")])
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("productsSet")
        var productsSet: MutableSet<Products>
)
```

And 'Products' entity has a List as an inverse mapping as:

```
@Entity(name = "products")
class Products(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="prd_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        var id: Integer,
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productsSet")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("productsSet")
        var categories: MutableSet<Categories>
)
```

My mapping table 'categories_product' has two columns 'cat_id' and 'prd_id' that references the 'categories' and 'products' table respectively.

I have a ProductsRepository and CategoriesRepository that implements CrudRepository.

Calling findAll() from mappedBy side which is ProductsRepository works fine, as shown below:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Cricket Bat",
      "price":10.0,
      "categories":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Sports",
            "description":"Sports items"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Spring Boot",
      "price":100.0,
      "categories":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Books",
            "description":"Book items"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

However, calling findAll() from owning side which is Categories returns all its products which contains its referenced categories as well, as shown below:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Sports",
      "description":"Sports items",
      "productsSet":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Cricket Bat",
            "price":10.0,
            "categories":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"Sports",
                  "description":"Sports items"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Books",
      "description":"Book items",
      "productsSet":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Spring Boot",
            "price":100.0,
            "categories":[
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"Books",
                  "description":"Book items"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How do I make findAll() from owning side (CategoriesRepository) return only its children not children's children as in the mapping side (ProductsRepository)?

Comment: Replace `@JsonIgnoreProperties("productsSet")` by `@JsonIgnoreProperties("categories")`? Or stop using your persistence model in your REST API, but instead use specifically designed classes that contains what you actually want to return in your API.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet it works! Yes, I see the advantage of returning specifically designed classes. Currently it's sufficient for my need to return the persistence classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I am listing the solution given by @JBNizet given in the comments. Thanks, JB Nizet!

When using @ManyToMany it's imperitive to include @JsonIgnoreProperties to avoid having StackOverFlow Exception due to recursive fetching of records.

So define @JsonIgnoreProperties on the owning side to ignore the child element as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "categories_product", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "cat_id")], inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "prd_id")])
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("categories")
        var productsSet: MutableSet<Products>
```

And define @JsonIgnoreProperties on the mapping side to ignore the parent element as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productsSet")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("productsSet")
        var categories: MutableSet<Categories>
```